# Your device isn't compatible with this version - No Carrier

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions, device-compatibility

My app is not shown on GooglePlay store search for some devices (e.g Intel JM1011, Lenovo TB2-X30F), and when I tried to access it through the browser I found it is not compatible with these devices as they have "**No Carrier**", although I mentioned all of the carrier required permissions in my app manifest to be not required.

So, what are the permissions that can cause the `No Carrier` compatibility issue other than phone and sms permissions?

That's the whole **manifest.xml** permissions I'm using:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<!-- Internet Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Network State Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<!-- GCM Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- For Getting current location on Google Maps -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Permissions for access the camera & capture both images & videos -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />

<!-- Allow Disk getting from and Caching on SD Card -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:required="false" />

<!-- call Permission -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    android:required="false" />

<!-- Vibrate Permission! -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"
    android:required="false" />

<permission
    android:name="ae.netaq.schoolvoice.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="ae.netaq.schoolvoice.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

Comment: Can you please also show the `uses-feature` lines if any?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri it's already there :) the only 2 I'm using is shown here

Comment: It might be that the error is misleading. The devices seems to support auto focus as well, so that doesn't seem to be the issue. What if you remove the specification of the `supports-screens` section?

Comment: actually I'm not able to make trial/error as when installing the app directly to any of these devices it works perfectly, I'm getting that only when I upload to the store, so if I'm going to just try anything, it would be along with the new update, I don't want to bother the users with a million updates in one day.
Do you have any idea how can I check that without pushing to the store?!!

Comment: Direct installation won't give issue since this attribute is for play store to access if a user/device is allowed to install / see this app. One way to test it out is use `alpha` / `beta` versioning in Google play store to test your changes. Only upload the app for Alpha testing and add yourself as alpha tester. You can probably see then on the play store about the compatibility of the newly released apk with the devices you mentioned above. It won't be released to end users this way.

Comment: nice idea, I will try that and see how it will ends

Comment: Are you sure that "No carrier" is the reason they are incompatible with your device, and not just the way your device is being named as it doesn't have a SIM card.

Can you add a screenshot of the web store incompatibility message to your question?